# Header file for obtaining data from Kinect for Point Cloud data

Tags: kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to find openni_grabber.h file in pcl/io folder. Do I need openni_grabber.h or grabber.h is enough for obtaining data from Kinect ? And also can anyone help me on functioning of pcd_io.h. Please post any proper documentation site or any site where it has been used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59364/header-file-for-obtaining-data-from-kinect-for-point-cloud-data./) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer the second question: The [PCL homepage](http://www.pointclouds.org) is a good starting point for everything PCL-related, including [tutorials](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/) and the [documentation of the io-module](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__io.html).

To integrate a kinect in ROS: have you tried setting it up using the [openni_camera stack](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera)? The published topics can then easily be subscribed to and accessed using PCL (see [PCL ROS overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Overview)).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2